# Why does my custom claim not show up as a claim after being added?

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, blazor-server-side

In a Blazor Server app, I add a claim through a Hook in OpenIdConnect like this:

```
builder.Services.Configure<MicrosoftIdentityOptions>(
options =>
{
  options. Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
  {
    OnTokenValidated = async (ctx) =>
    {
       AuthService service = new AuthService(builder.Configuration);
        service.EnrichClaims(ctx);
    }

  };
});
```

This works just fine.

Here is the code that then adds a claim:

```
 var claim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, "44");
 identity.AddClaim(claim);
 context?.Principal?.AddIdentity(identity);
 var sIdtest = context.Principal.GetSid();
```

This works to show the SID that I just added.

But now I want to view this information later in the app:

```
 var authState = await authenticationState;

 var user = authState?.User;

 this.Sid = user.GetSid();
```

This code runs, but Sid is null.  When I check the debugger, the identity that I added with the claim is missing.

Why is the identity and claim missing?  This makes no sense, as I just added it, and confirmed that it is there.

Comment: Perhaps useful ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71012036/microsoft-identity-web-ontokenvalidated-event-doesnt-seem-to-play-nicely-with-a

Comment: Yes, that was useful! The issue was that I was not awaiting the call to the AuthService.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code slightly to ensure that async/await was being used correctly:

```
 builder.Services.Configure<MicrosoftIdentityOptions> 
(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
options => {

  options.Events ??= new OpenIdConnectEvents();
  options.Events.OnTokenValidated += async context => {
     AuthService service = new AuthService(builder.Configuration);
     await service.EnrichClaims(context);
 };
});
```

And in the Auth Service:

```
 var principal = context. Principal;

 //Already has the claim.
 if(principal.HasClaim(c=> c.Type == "AppUserId")) {
      return;
 }
 var objectId = context?.Principal?.GetObjectId();
 var appUserId = await this.GetAppUserId(objectId);

 var claim = new Claim("AppUserId", appUserId.ToString());
 var identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
 identity.AddClaim(claim);
 context?.Principal?.AddIdentity(identity);
```